# Copy the produced executable in my root dir with dune

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

Let's say I have a simple project with the following structure:

```
.
├── dune-project
└── src
└── bin
    ├── dune
    └── main.ml
```

`dune-project`

```
(lang dune 2.7)
(name myproject)

(package
 (name myproject)
 (synopsis "myproject")
 (description "Basic project")
)
```

`dune`

```
(executable
 (name main)
 (public_name myproject)
)
```

When compiling with `dune build` I have a new directory `_build` with the following structure:

```
_build
├── default
│   ├── dune-project
│   ├── META.myproject
│   ├── myproject.dune-package
│   ├── myproject.install
│   └── src
│       └── bin
│           ├── dune
│           ├── main.exe
│           └── main.ml
├── install
│   └── default
│       ├── bin
│       │   └── myproject -> ../../../default/src/bin/main.exe
│       └── lib
│           └── myproject
│               ├── dune-package -> ../../../../default/myproject.dune-package
│               └── META -> ../../../../default/META.myproject
└── log
```

So dune is able to create a symlink from `main.exe` to `myproject` but I actually want `myproject` to be in `.` and not in `_build/install/default/bin`

I tried three things:

- Add the rule `(promote (into ../../))` in my `dune` file. It actually copies `main.exe` and not `myproject` in the source directory and `dune clean` doesn't delete `main.exe` in the root dir
- Add the following rule in my `dune` file:

  ```
  (rule
   (target myproject)
   (deps   ../../myproject)
   (action (copy %{target} %{deps}))
  )
  ```

  which gives me the following error:

  ```
  ❯ dune build
  File "src/bin/dune", line 6, characters 0-88:
   6 | (rule
   7 |  (target myproject)
   8 |  (deps   ../../myproject)
   9 |  (action (copy %{target} %{deps}))
  10 | )
  Error: No rule found for myproject
  Error: Dependency cycle between the following files:
     _build/default/src/bin/myproject
  Done: 0/0 (jobs: 0)%
  ```
- Add the following rule in my `dune` file:

  ```
  (rule
   (target main.exe)
   (deps   ../../myproject)
   (action (copy %{target} %{deps}))
  )
  ```

  which gives me the following error:

  ```
  ❯ dune build
  Error: Multiple rules generated for _build/default/src/bin/main.exe:
  - src/bin/dune:6
  - src/bin/dune:2
  Done: 0/0 (jobs: 0)%
  ```

And honestly I don't know what else I can do. I read the manual and can't find a solution. I wouldn't mind if I could just type `dune run` but since dune allows to build multiple executables, I understand it's not an option. I'd like to be able to write `dune run myproject` since I'm using the public name of my executables but dune can't find it. So I just want to have `myproject` in my root directory so I can just type `./myproject` and be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know about `dune exec`? It is what you call `dune run` I believe.

From the root of your project, you can do `dune exec ./bin/main.exe`.

Comment: Oh, actually `dune exec myproject` is working. Thanks a lot. I'd still like to know why my rule is not working to copy the executable in the root directory but that's already more than enough

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [`promote`](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html?highlight=promote#promote). For instance,

```
(executable
 (name my_tool)
 (promote
  (until-clean)
  (into ../bin)))
```