# Copying a newly builded file as a Dune's stanza

Tags: ocaml, copying, ocaml-dune

I have written a library in OCaml with all of its sources located in `lib` folder.
I also prepared "facade" executables in `bin` folder.
Now I would like to prepare some examples how to use the above mentioned executables.
To do this I need to either copy an executable beforehand or (preferably) tell Dune to use a newly created one after build.

And here is my question.
Dune's `copy_files` stanza does not allow<sup>1</sup> me to copy from `_build` folder.
Is there any other way to use fresh executables each time after building or do I need to copy them at some point and keep up to date?

Below is the structure of the project (in case verbal description was misleading in any way).

```
root
   lib <- source
   bin <- frontend for source
   examples <- how to use the above frontend
```

<sup>1</sup> By not allow I mean the following usage of this stanza:
`( copy_files %{project_root}/_build/default/bin/program.exe  )`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373805/copy-the-produced-executable-in-my-root-dir-with-dune
Unless you create a Makefile that copies the generated executable to the root, I don't know any other way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution, as suggested by @Lhooq, might be to use `dune exec` command with `--root` parameter.

In regard to the provided scenario, if we make a script:

```
   dune exec --root=../.. ./bin/some_program.exe 
(* 
   Where 'some_program' is the name of an .ml file located in bin folder.
   I assumed here that the program is compiled to native code, not to bytecode (hence the .exe).
*)
```

and place it in `examples` directory, then by invoking it we will actually run the latest build of the program defined in `some_program.ml` located in `bin` folder.

And just to make things clear: `bin` folder does NOT contain any compiled files (neither .exe nor .bc) .